# Commutative ring with an ideal that contains all the nonunits

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Is there an example of a commutative ring with an ideal that contains all the non-units?

I was trying to think of some subring of $\mathbb Q$, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Great question! Look up Local Ring.

Comment: Technically $\mathbb Q$ is such a ring. A rather boring example; every field is a local ring.

Comment: The ring $\mathbb Z_{(2)}\subset \mathbb Q$ consisting of fractions with odd denominator is an example of what you require.

Comment: Yes, and the fractions with even numerators is the ideal of nonunits.

Comment: Hmm, are there rings where this is the only nonzero, proper ideal?

Comment: Yes. Georges' example is one of what is called a "Discrete Valuation Ring", which is a special kind of local ring with the property that the nonzero proper ideals of $R$ are precisely the powers $\mathfrak m^k$ for $k \ge 1$, where $\mathfrak m \subset R$ is the maximal ideal. Consider the local ring $R/\mathfrak m^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Atiyah-Macdonald*'s book: "*Introduction to commutative algebra*" explains what Jake says:

> **Proposition 1.6.** i) Let $A$ be a ring and $\mathfrak{m} \neq (1)$ an ideal of $A$ such that
>   every $x \in A - \mathfrak{m}$ is a unit in $A$. Then $A$ is a local ring and $\mathfrak{m}$ is its maximum ideal.
>   ....
>   ii) Let $A$ be a ring and $\mathfrak{m}$ a maximal ideal of $A$, such that every element of
>   $1 + \mathfrak{m}$ (i.e., every $1 + x$, where $x \in \mathfrak{m}$) is a unit in $A$. Then $A$ is a local ring.
>
> *Proof.* i) Every ideal $\neq (1)$ consists on non-units, hence is contained in $\mathfrak{m}$. Hence $\mathfrak{m}$ is the only maximum ideal of $A$.

So note that for a commutative ring $R$ these are equivalent:

> 1. The ring $R$ is local  ,
> 2. The set $m$ of non-units is an ideal,
> 3. The set $m$ of non-units is the only maximal ideal.

For example the ring $k[[X]]$, where $k$ is a field.

Answer (score 4):

Take the ring $R$ of $2 \times 2$ matrices $A = [a_{ij}]$ with $a_{11} = a_{22}$ and $a_{21} = 0$
over a field $F,$ and let $I$ be the ideal consisting of those matrices in $R$ with with $a_{11} = a_{22} = 0.$

Comment: This is correct. The ring $R$ is isomorphic to the ring of dual numbers $F[X]/(X^2)$. We commutative algebraists can smell in Geoff a member of the rival gang of non-commutative algebraists :-) Anyway, +1

Comment: @Georges: Yes, upper triangular matrices with constant main diagonal entries are my natural choice of local ring, but usually non-commutative!

Answer (score 3):

Take $R=\mathbb Z / 9 \mathbb Z$ and $I=3R$. Then $I=\{0, 3, 6\}$, which are exactly the non-units.

More generally, $R=\mathbb Z / p^2 \mathbb Z$ and $I=pR$, where $p$ is a prime.